# Could Civi or Drupal Rules be used to aggregate ratings for services?

Tags: civirules, drupal-rules

We want to implement a feedback system for services (these would be CiviCRM Contacts). Think of it like eBay feedback with an overall rating and some sub-categories like speed of dispatch, comms, description of item, etc.

Each of these ratings would be stored as a Custom Field against each Contact.

Feedback would be gathered via Activities. Could Civi or Drupal Rules be used to calculate averages (based on multiple Activity submissions) and update the custom fields on the Contact?

Answer (score 4):

You would do this with an extension. Check out the [Summary Fields](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields) extension for inspiration. It's similar to your goal, just geared toward donations and event participation.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of. Probably you will need to write your own (relatively simple) sql query within a hook (or a function called by rules). Check out the [mysql docs for AVG](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-avg-function.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do exactly but possibly CiviRules (https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) would enable you to create specific actions and conditions for this